# Why wont my footer show up?

Tags: html, footer

I dont know why my footer wont show up. Can someone show me or help me?

Here is my fiddle example:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/dutju8b4/`
```

Thanks,
Tyler

Comment: it does, it is just 0 pixels wide because the div is empty.

Answer (score 1):

set the inner div width to 100%

```
<div id="footer" style="height:5%; background-color:dimgray;width:100%"></div>
```

Comment: what browser are you using? It shows up in chrome right under the header

Comment: I added that exact line of code to mine but it isnt showing up. I am using chrome.

Comment: Also, does positioning that as fixed keep it at the bottom.?

Comment: Thanks, got any ideas on why my footer isnt showing up?